# How can I rotate an image I load with filedialog.askopenfilename?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to browse an image and show it, which I'm already able to do.
I'd like to rotate this image on screen clicking on a button, how can I do it?

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Exif Viewer')
root.geometry('500x550')
global image_loaded


def browse_image():
    global image_loaded

    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select An Image",
                                               filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"), ("png files", "*.png")))
    image_loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    image_loaded_label = Label(image=image_loaded).pack()


browse_button = Button(root, padx=20, pady=5, text="Load image", command=browse_image).pack()
rotate_left_button = Button(root, padx=10, pady=5, text="Rotate left").pack()
rotate_right_button = Button(root, padx=10, pady=5, text="Rotate right").pack()
exit_button = Button(root, padx=20, pady=5, text="Exit", command=root.quit).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you read through the [documentation for PIL and the Image object](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#examples) before asking this question?

Comment: Look [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate)

Comment: Yes, I tried it with that function but I'm not able to update the view

Comment: Please show what you tried. The code you posted shows no attempt at rotating the image.

Comment: I tried using rotate(), but I was not able to update the label view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate an image with the `rotate` method of an Image object.

```
def browse_image():
    global image_object, image_loaded_label

    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select An Image",
                                               filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"), ("png files", "*.png")))
    image_object = Image.open(root.filename)
    image_loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    image_loaded_label = Label(image=image_loaded)
    image_loaded_label.pack()
    image_loaded_label.image = image_loaded

def rotate_image(direction):
    global image_object
    angle = {"left":90, "right":-90}[direction]
    image_object = image_object.rotate(angle)
    rotated_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    image_loaded_label.config(image = rotated_tk)
    image_loaded_label.image = rotated_tk #Prevent garbage collection


browse_button = Button(root, padx=20, pady=5, text="Load image", command=browse_image).pack()
rotate_left_button = Button(root, padx=10, pady=5, text="Rotate left", command = lambda: rotate_image("left")).pack()
rotate_right_button = Button(root, padx=10, pady=5, text="Rotate right", command = lambda: rotate_image("right")).pack()
exit_button = Button(root, padx=20, pady=5, text="Exit", command=root.quit).pack()
```

In order to use the Image object it is on a separate line to the PhotoImage and is called `image_object`. The `image_loaded_label.image` line is to prevent garbage collection, which would cause the image to not appear.
I've added commands to both buttons which call `rotate_image`. This takes the direction as a parameter, which is then turned into the number of degrees anticlockwise to turn the image. The `rotate` method of `image_object` is used to rotate the image which is then assigned to `image_object`, replacing the original Image object. Then it is made into a PhotoImage as before and the label is configured to show it. The last line is garbage collection prevention again.

Comment: It's better to use another variable for the rotated image. On my computer, rotating an image 360 times 1 degree adds artefacts.

Comment: That problem doesn't seem to occur with 90 degree rotations, also (I assume) the user wants a 180 degree rotation when they press one of the buttons twice, so this is the most straightforward way to implement it. Otherwise I'd have to have another variable to keep track of the current angle.

Comment: Try but I will leave my comment there for anyone that finds this in the future. They might have different requirements.

Comment: Thanks! This is working! But it always changes the images dimension, can I use this resized_image= image_loaded.resize((300,205), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image) before  doin image_loaded_label.image = image_loaded?

Comment: That should work, you could also try adding `expand = True` to `image_object.rotate(angle)`.